# How can I same width as th for td in colspan td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I have html table layout below:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3">Name</td>
                    <td>foo</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I want this layout with jquery function and code is here:
**jquery**

```js
function createTable() {
 var mytable = $('<table></table>').appendTo('body');
 
 var thead = $('<thead></thead>').appendTo(mytable);
   
 var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(thead);
 
 for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  $('<th></th>').text(j).appendTo(row);
 }
}

function addName() {

  var CategoryRow = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo('table');
  
  var col = $('<td></td>').attr({'colspan':3}).appendTo(CategoryRow);
  
  var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(col);
  
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
   $('<td></td>').text('a'+j).appendTo(row);
  }
  
  $(row).find('td:eq(0)').text('name');
}

createTable();
addName();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now the prob is when I use jquery to append this layout, **table cell width that is in colspan table cell not same as table heading**

**Note** If I save dynamic generate table and run then layout is okay.

Comment: use th colspan...

Comment: 1 always use *valid* html (nested tables) (despite your comment) 2 use th colspan.  3 use `<colgroup>` in your nested tables to set all the column widths the same

Comment: thanks @freedomn-m can you provide a html table layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have solved this by replacing td > tbody.*

**Using this html code, I have achieve what I need.**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <tbody>
                <td rowspan="3">Name</td>
                <td>foo</td>
                <td>bar</td>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tbody>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```